# Haskell's do syntax and its pattern matching behaviour

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, state, do-notation

I am currently trying to understand the do notation as taught in: http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more ...Here it is applied to simple functions and not a monad.

```
type Stack = [Int]

push :: Int -> Stack -> ((), Stack)
push a stack = ((),a:stack)

pop :: Stack -> (Int, Stack)
pop (x:xs) = (x, xs)
```

I dont understand the do-syntax fully, I am curious: Is this

```
turnipStack2 :: Stack -> (Int, Stack)
turnipStack = do
  push 3 
  c <- pop
  pop
```

.. the same as

```
turnipStack :: Stack -> (Int, Stack)
turnipStack = do
  push 3 
  c <- pop
  return c
```

If so, why is that. And could I have done the first mentioned without writing `pop` in the end. In that case I get an error although I don't understand it.

Comment: "without writing pop in the end" The `<-` in do-notation is not really a function, but syntax sugar that is desugared to actual functions like `>>=`. And the desugaring requires that some monadic statement exists below the `<-`.

Comment: "What do you mean by 'desugared to actual functions like `>>=` ". Syntactic sugar here means something that is easier to read for humans, but entails some more complex operation. As mentioned in my comment below I use it equivalent to the LYAH example 1:1 (stackManip example).

Comment: @danidiaz and what does monadic statements encompass in this regard? Would those be `fail`, `return` and the binding-operators?

Comment: @Piscator "something that is easier to read for humans, but entails some more complex operation". Yes, that's what do-notation is. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54577848/haskell-desugaring-state-do-notation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39614816/monadic-desugaring-haskell It lets you use imperative-looking syntax to combine  monadic values.  You can ask ghci for the type of `>>=` with `:type (>>=)`, you can pass `>>=` as an argument to a suitable higher-order function, but you can't do that with `<-` or an isolated `do`. Also `return` is not syntax sugar, but just another function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to actually get this working you need to change the signatures to use the *state monad*. Currently your `do` block refers to the `(Stack->)` monad, aka `Reader Stack`, but you want `State Stack` instead.

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.State

push :: Int -> State Stack ()
push a = state $ \stack -> ((),a:stack)

pop :: State Stack Int
pop = state $ \(x:xs) -> (x, xs)

turnipStack2 :: State Stack Int
turnipStack2 = do
  push 3 
  c <- pop
  pop
```

This is *not* equivalent to

```
 do
  push 3
  c <- pop
  return c
```

The latter just pops off the one element you stored again, and then gives it back. This could actually be simplified to

```
 do
  push 3
  pop
```

thanks to the monad law `do{ x<-a; return x } ≡ a` (*right identity*).

By contrast, `turnipStack2` first pops off the `3` you pushed, but doesn't use it (it's just discarded) then pops off *another* element which is the result value.

Applying the right identity law in reverse, you could however write it thus:

```
 do
  push 3 
  _ <- pop
  d <- pop
  return d
```

Binding an unused variable can be omitted, so

```
turnipStack2 = do
  push 3 
  pop
  d <- pop
  return d
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand. In the LYAH they give the example of stackManip which is exactly equal to my turnipStack2. Are you saying that it will not work without the `stack` Monad? 
Furthermore when I call my two functions the output seems to be equivalent. I dont know if that has to do with that it is using a `Reader` rather than `State Stack`-Monad. 
@danidiaz points out something above. I don't know if he is referring to that you can use `do`-notation on a function that is not monadic without getting the benefits of the short cut (sugar)that the `do`-notation will be on an actual monad.

Comment: @Piskator well, your two functions give the same result because you're working in the wrong monad – you're (accidentally) using the reader monad, which just takes the stack as a constant environment parameter. This would have become obvious if you had tried to do more with the popped values, since the types don't actually make sense.

Comment: Does it use a 'reader Monad' by default unless I deliberately declare that it is for instance a State Monad I want to use?

Comment: @Piskator not so much “by default” as, you forced it to use the function-monad by giving a function-signature

Comment: Ok, I think I understand partially;  It uses a Reader Monad because the type signature for the function forced it to use `((->) r) `-Monad, that is the function-Monad. And the specific function I used also used a `Reader`-Monad as part of the functions that were used !?

Comment: That sounds about right.